# FileZilla alternative with site manager search

Tags: ftp

I'm looking for an alternative on FileZilla where I can search on sites. I have a big list of sites in my site manager it takes me to much time to search for a site every time. For the rest I only use the basics of FileZilla up/download files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on Windows, WinSCP has [incremental site search](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login#management).

[image]

It can even [import sites/sessions from FileZilla](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import). It supports folders, similarly to FileZilla, too.

And it supports a larger set of protocols and features than FileZilla does.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*